# replace string with operator and macros in matlab

Tags: string, matlab, macros, replace

I have 2 var `a` and `b`.
I want to get a function to form from the user.

```
str='operator'
```

it can be either `'<'`, `'=='`, `'>'`, `'||'`, `'&&'` and so on.
I used `enum` and `switch`-`case`.
even though it works, for many functions this solution is not elegant at all.

Is there a way to evaluate the string and use what within it? something like macro?
example: `str='=='`
`valuation(a str b)` ==> executes `a==b`

I was looking for information about macros in matlab and I couldn't find a clear answer. so an explanation about what exist and how to use it might be nice (links are also good).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a MAP:

```
operators={'+',@plus;'-',@minus;'==',@eq};
mapObj = containers.Map(operators(:,1),operators(:,2));
```

This list is incomplete, If you don't know the function name (`plus`) for an operator (`+`) type in `doc +`

To use it, get the function handle out of the map:

```
f=mapObj('+')
```

and evaluate it:

```
f(a,b)
```

Comment: Thanks! I shall try it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eval` :

```
  a = 1;
  b = 3;
  st = '>';  %Take from user
  stWithOp = ['a' st 'b' ];
  eval(stWithOp);
```

---

However, beware that getting the string from the user might allow him to inject malicious code. For example a user may enter:

```
 %DO NOT TRY THIS AT HOME!
 st = '; rmdir(''C:\'') ';
```

Comment: Is there a way to identify malicious inputs? I guess in this case I can check the input length is no longer than 1. but in general?

Comment: `==` has length two, so you must allow at least this length. Depending on where you place spaces either `;f` will call `f` with parameter `'b'` or `+5` would add a leading digit to `b`.